# Short story where everyone must be equal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a short story about a dystopian society that I read in a High School English Lit book. I am pretty sure it was my Jr. year, circa 1991, the book was a few years old, probably published in mid to late 80s. I went to High School in Oklahoma, the story was in English.

I do not know the name of the author either, but I don't believe it was anyone well known (or at least not well-known to an 11th grader in the early 90s).

The story is set in a world where everyone must be equal. The powers that be implement this by handicapping people that have "better" qualities. For instance, I believe there was a ballet dancer on the TV, and the narrator comments that she must be really pretty to have to wear such an ugly mask.

The narrator was a man watching TV at home. His wife seemed to be kind of dull, and he was periodically hit with a shock collar or something to keep him from thinking too deep a thought (he was above average intelligence and this was his handicap).

Comment: It’s by ray Bradbury

Comment: @CBredlow - Nope. Vonnegut. See Mark Olson's answer.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yup, that would explain why I couldn’t find it. I knew this question was posted before and I remember this story too and thought it was him

Comment: "Vonnegut" and "I don't believe it was anyone well know" means I needed to go to a better high school.

Comment: To be fair to the Original Poster's (@KevinMilner) high school, I also read this story in High School English class, and it was before I had heard of Kurt Vonnegut.  This was the story that put Kurt Vonnegut "on the map" for me.  (There's always a first time to be introduced to an author, and this story in high school English class is a great place for it.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would be "*Harrison Bergeron*" by Kurt Vonnegut.

> THE YEAR WAS 2081, and everybody was finally equal. They weren't only equal
>   before God and the law. They were equal every which way. Nobody was smarter
>   than anybody else. Nobody was better looking than anybody else. Nobody was
>   stronger or quicker than anybody else. All this equality was due to the
>   211th, 212th, and 213th Amendments to the Constitution, and to the unceasing
>   vigilance of agents of the United States Handicapper General.

and

> "Yup," said George. He tried to think a little about the ballerinas. They
>   weren't really very good-no better than anybody else would have been, anyway.
>   They were burdened with sashweights and bags of birdshot, and their faces
>   were masked, so that no one, seeing a free and graceful gesture or a pretty
>   face, would feel like something the cat drug in. George was toying with the
>   vague notion that maybe dancers shouldn't be handicapped. But he didn't get
>   very far with it before another noise in his ear radio scattered his
>   thoughts.

You can read it online [here](http://www.tnellen.com/westside/harrison.pdf).

Comment: Thats it! Thank you! I'll accept in 2 minutes :)